Dynamic links in firebase and Email Link Auth
I'm trying to add email link authentication to my expo app with firebase, but it needs a dynamic link and in dynamic links page it says that it is deprecated and there is no get started option.
How can I add it as the documentation says that it will continue working for email link auth but there is no way to add it?
I searched everywhere for a way to add it but didn't find anything all tutorials are before the deprecation.

Firebase is currently actively working on migration from Firebase Dynamic links (FDL). They are aware of this and are working on a resolution.
Firebase added the button back to the Firebase dynamic links. If you click the link you should be able to add FDL to your Firebase project using the continue anyway button. If you are still unable to do so I would recommend raising a ticket with Firebase.

The issue is currently being tracked here
Source
